# What's the meaning of "Beyond the Rhetoric" in this context?

Tags: meaning

In these sentences

> 1. This series looks **beyond the rhetoric**.
> 2. Kenya should move **beyond mere rhetoric** to fight off wanton corruption.
> 3. Such transition teams will delve far **beyond the rhetoric** of hashtags.

What's the meaning of "beyond the rhetoric"?

In my point of view, the meaning should be "do not use rhetoric words or languages to influence others".

Comment: *Rhetoric*, in this instance, just means empty words (or pointless argument).

Comment: could you elaborate your respond. why they should put redundant words in a sentence?

Comment: Sorry. [*Empty words*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/empty+words) is idomatic. I should have avoided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of [Rhetoric](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/rhetoric):

> language that is intended to influence people and that may not be
>   honest or reasonable.

In your first sentence, It means beyond what is said about it. Suppose you saw an advertisement of a series and decided to watch it. After watching it, you thought that it was better than what was said about it in the advertisement. Now, your friend who has seen the advertisement asked you about the show and you told him it was beyond the Rhetoric, meaning it is better than what is generally perceived about it.

In the second sentence, it means Kenya should do more than just vocally condemning corruption.

The third sentence means something like, Such transition teams will do more than what is said about them (by people) in hastags.